# How to automatically generate a PDF of a website?

Tags: python, ruby, pdf

I have a website that has some charts and graphs made using JavaScript libraries.  What's a good way to, server-side, auto-generate the HTML, CSS, and JS, and then capture the result in a PDF / PNG / JPG?  I'd like to auto-generate reports and email them to my users.

Any programming language is fine, but Ruby / Rails would be best.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of the [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) project. With the help of the webkit rendering enginge it produces PDFs from a webpage. It offers Python bindings. Ruby bindings are also available: [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit)

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is a good tool to use. I've just used it to generate 500+ pdf documents in one day using a rake task. If you're interested with gems that take advantage of wkhtmltopdf, then you can try [WickedPDF](http://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) or [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit).